# Stop watch is not working

Tags: android

I can see the thread for date and time running. But there is no thread for stop watch. what could be the problem?

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private Button Start, Reset, Stop;
private EditText stop_watch, lblDate, lblTime;

public MainActivity() {

}

private final UpdateClockThread ucThread = new UpdateClockThread();
private final StopwatchThread swThread = new StopwatchThread();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    stop_watch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    lblTime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    lblDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    init();

    Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startactionPerformed();
        }
    });

    Stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            stopactionPerformed();
        }
    });

    Reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            resetactionPerformed();
        }
    });

}

public void init() {
swThread.setDaemon(true);
ucThread.setDaemon(true);
swThread.start(); // this doesent seem to wrk..
ucThread.start();
}

/** Listens to the Start/Stop/Resume button. */

void startactionPerformed() {
    swThread.go();
}

void stopactionPerformed() {
    swThread.noGo();
}

void resetactionPerformed() {
    swThread.reset();
}

/** A thread that updates the current date & time. */
private class UpdateClockThread extends Thread {
/** The actual work of the thread. */
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String month = Integer.toString(now.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
                    String date = Integer.toString(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    String year = Integer.toString(now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                    String hour = Integer.toString(now.get(Calendar.HOUR));
                    if (hour.equals("0")) hour = "12";
                    String minute = Integer.toString(now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                    if (minute.length() == 1) minute = "0" + minute;
                    String second = Integer.toString(now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                    if (second.length() == 1) second = "0" + second;
                    String ampm = now.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM ? "AM" : "PM";
                    lblDate.setText(month + "/" + date + "/" + year);
                    lblTime.setText(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + ampm);
                }
            });

            try {
                sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
        }
    }
}

/** A thread that keeps track of the stop watch & updates
 * the display accordingly.
*/
class StopwatchThread extends Thread {
    /** Whether or not stop watch is running. */
    private boolean going = false;
    /** Stores elapsed milliseconds of previous runs. */
    private long prevElapsed = 0;
    /** Stores beginning time of this run. */
    private Date startDate = new Date();

    /** Returns elapsed time in milliseconds.
     *@return The elapsed time
     */
    private long elapsedTime() {
        return prevElapsed + (going ? new Date().getTime() - startDate.getTime() : 0);
    }
    /** Changes the number of elapsed milliseconds into a string.
     *@param time Number of elapsed milliseconds
     *@return The elapsed time as a string.
     */
    private String msToString(long time) {
        String ms, sec, min;
        if (time % 10 >= 5) //round to nearest hundredth
            time += 5;
        ms = Long.toString(time % 1000);
        while (ms.length() < 3)
            ms = "0" + ms;
        ms = ms.substring(0, ms.length() - 1);
    time /= 1000;
    sec = Long.toString(time % 60);
    if (sec.length() == 1) sec = "0" + sec;
    time /= 60;
    min = Long.toString(time);
    stop_watch.setText(min);
    return min + ":" + sec + "." + ms;
}

    /** Called when the stop watch is to go.
    */
    public void go() {
        startDate = new Date();
        going = true;
    }
    /** Called when the stop watch is to stop.
     */
    public void noGo() {
        prevElapsed = elapsedTime();
        going = false;
    }
    /** Resets the stop watch.
     */
    public void reset() {
        going = false;
        prevElapsed = 0;
    }
    /** Adds a lap to the list.
     */

    /** Main code of the thread.
     */

    public void run() {

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                stop_watch.setText(msToString(elapsedTime()));          
            }
        });
        yield();
    }
}
```

}

I can see the thread for date and time running. But there is no thread for stop watch. what could be the problem?

How can i start the stopwatch thread.. Please help..

I have two daemon thread in my program.. but log shows that only one is active.. even if i terminate the active thread. stopwatch still doesnt wrk. i tried a lot. but im not able to figure out that where is the problem..

DalvikVM[localhost:8633]

Thread [<1> main] (Running)

Thread [<8> Binder Thread #2] (Running)

Thread [<7> Binder Thread #1] (Running)

Daemon Thread [<10> Thread-10] (Running)

Comment: You should explain your problem in a more specific way. If you put a bunch of code, don't expect someone to fix it :P

Comment: I tried to explain in bit more detail.. There is nothing more which i cud share.. every thing is wrking fine.. except one of the two thread.. dont know why its not running.. And if im trying to restart that thread im getting force close issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your StopwatchThread's `run()` method.

It runs a single task (calling `stop_watch.setText()`) on the UI thread, then stops. 
You don't have a loop of any kind, even though you have a promising-looking "going" variable defined.

Add in a while loop similar to that in your UpdateClockThread, and I think you will find it works as expected.

Comment: Yay it wrked. But why is it lagging a bit? Its not smooth, nano sec is freezing.. Its not as smooth as the stopwatch app which came pre-installed in my phone..

Comment: That is an entirely different problem that will require a lot of debugging work from you. One major red flag for me is the large number of resources that you re-allocate in every iteration of your UpdateClockThread. I would recommend reading through the Android developer's [Designing for Performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/performance.html) page.